# What is the expected number of dice rolls to roll any number n times?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expected-value

I know that the expected number of rolls to roll a number x is 6, and from that I'm guessing that the expected number of rolls to roll an x n times is 6n. But I don't know the expected value if we're not looking for a specific x, but rather any number that gets rolled n times first.

Answer (score 3):

Let $E(x_1,\ldots,x_6,n)$ be the expected number of rolls where $x_i$ means face $i$ has been rolled $x_i$ times. We want to compute $E(0,\ldots,0, n)$ for some $n$.

We have
$E(x_1,\ldots,x_6,n) = 0$ if $\max(x_1, \ldots, x_6) = n$, but otherwise:

$$E(x_1,\ldots, x_6, n) = 1 + \dfrac{1}{6} \left(E(x_1+1,x_2,\ldots,x_6, n) + \ldots + E(x_1,\ldots,x_5,x_6+1, n)\right) $$

Cobbling together a quick Python script, I get this for the first ten values of $n$ (decimals rounded off to second position):

```
1 1 or 1.00
2 1223/324 or 3.77
3 4084571/559872 or 7.30
4 247150321423/22039921152 or 11.21
5 56252877655712005/3656158440062976 or 15.39
6 2597868106693535971/131621703842267136 or 19.74
7 1004137746946400066467061/41451359947637504606208 or 24.22
8 1511870922130873413914611/52461877433728716767232 or 28.82
9 796097507230553992646636993684021/23764434735722193898380170625024 or 33.50
10 17392183399770252095858075799290840376365/454658218573929784111766025256801665024 or 38.25
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how to do this analytically, but I wrote a simulation in $\texttt R$:

```
rm(list=ls())

N <- 10000
n <- 2

roll <- function(u) {
  if(u < 1/6)
    return(1)
  else if(u < 2/6)
    return(2)
  else if(u < 3/6)
    return(3)
  else if(u < 4/6)
    return(4)
  else if(u < 5/6)
    return(5)
  else
    return(6)
}

num_rolls <- rep(0, N)

for(i in 1:N) {
  current_rolls <- rep(0,6)
  while(max(current_rolls) < n) {
    current_roll <- roll(runif(1))
    current_rolls[current_roll] <- current_rolls[current_roll] + 1
  }
  num_rolls[i] <- sum(current_rolls)
}

print(mean(num_rolls))
```

Here's the rough mean values for $n=2,3,\ldots,10$:
\begin{array}{l|l}
n & \text{Expected number of rolls}\\\hline
2 & 3.75\\
3 & 7.28\\
4 & 11.18\\
5 & 15.37\\
6 & 19.74\\
7 & 24.20\\
8 & 28.84\\
9 & 33.48\\
10 & 38.36
\end{array}

There's definitely a linear trend, but that's about all that can be said from this data.

Answer (score 1):

**The Exponential Generating Function**

The exponential generating function for the number of ways to get exactly $d$ faces appearing $n-1$ times and the other faces less than $n-1$ times on a given number of rolls is
$$
\overbrace{\vphantom{{\sum_1^2}^6}\quad\binom{6}{d}\quad}^{\substack{\text{choose the $d$}\\[2pt]\text{of $6$ faces}}}\overbrace{\vphantom{{\sum_1^2}^6}\left(\frac{x^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}\right)^d}^{\substack{\text{$d$ faces appear}\\\text{$n-1$ times}}}\overbrace{\left(\sum_{j=0}^{n-2}\frac{x^j}{j!}\right)^{6-d}}^{\substack{\text{$6-d$ faces appear}\\\text{$\lt n-1$ times}}}\tag1
$$
That is, the probability that after $r$ rolls, we have exactly $d$ faces appearing $n-1$ times and the other faces less than $n-1$ times is
$$
\frac{r!}{6^r}\left[x^r\right]\binom{6}{d}\left(\frac{x^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}\right)^d\left(\sum_{j=0}^{n-2}\frac{x^j}{j!}\right)^{6-d}\tag2
$$
Given that $d$ faces have appeared $n-1$ times after $r$ rolls, there is a $\frac{d}6$ probability that on the next roll, one face will have appeared $n$ times. Thus, the probability of having the first face appearing $n$ times after $r+1$ rolls is
$$
\begin{align}
&\frac{r!}{6^r}\left[x^r\right]\sum_{d=1}^6\frac{d}6\binom{6}{d}\left(\frac{x^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}\right)^d\left(\sum_{j=0}^{n-2}\frac{x^j}{j!}\right)^{6-d}\\
&=\frac{r!}{6^r}\left[x^r\right]\sum_{d=1}^6\binom{5}{d-1}\left(\frac{x^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}\right)^d\left(\sum_{j=0}^{n-2}\frac{x^j}{j!}\right)^{6-d}\\
&=\frac{r!}{6^r}\left[x^r\right]\sum_{d=0}^5\binom{5}{d}\left(\frac{x^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}\right)^{d+1}\left(\sum_{j=0}^{n-2}\frac{x^j}{j!}\right)^{5-d}\\
&=\frac{r!}{6^r}\left[x^r\right]\frac{x^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}\left(\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\frac{x^j}{j!}\right)^5\tag3
\end{align}
$$

---

**The Expectation**

Therefore, if we define the degree $6n-6$ polynomial
$$
P_n(x)=\frac{x^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}\left(\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\frac{x^j}{j!}\right)^5\tag4
$$
The expected number of rolls for the first face to appear $n$ times is
$$
E_n(\color{#C00}{r+1})=\sum_{r=0}^{6n-6}(\color{#C00}{r+1})\frac{r!}{6^r}\left[x^r\right]P_n(x)\tag5
$$
The first $10$ expectations match those computed by Marcus Andrews:
$$
\begin{array}{r|r|l}
n&\text{approx}&\text{expected number of rolls}\\\hline
1&1.0000&1\\
2&3.7747&\frac{1223}{324}\\
3&7.2955&\frac{4084571}{559872}\\
4&11.2138&\frac{247150321423}{22039921152}\\
5&15.3858&\frac{56252877655712005}{3656158440062976}\\
6&19.7374&\frac{2597868106693535971}{131621703842267136}\\
7&24.2245&\frac{1004137746946400066467061}{41451359947637504606208}\\
8&28.8185&\frac{1511870922130873413914611}{52461877433728716767232}\\
9&33.4995&\frac{796097507230553992646636993684021}{23764434735722193898380170625024}\\
10&38.2533&\frac{17392183399770252095858075799290840376365}{454658218573929784111766025256801665024}\\
11&43.0690&\frac{101511378167172386781645248411365620974025241}{2356948205087252000835395074931259831484416}\\
12&47.9382&\frac{6101342241457232211864797021754203037755744243}{127275203074711608045111334046288030900158464}
\end{array}
$$

---

**The Variance**

The variance of the number of rolls for the first face to appear $n$ times is
$$
E_n\!\left((r+1)^2\right)-\left(E_n(r+1)\right)^2\tag6
$$
where $E_n(r+1)$ is computed above and
$$
E_n\!\left(\color{#C00}{(r+1)^2}\right)=\sum_{r=0}^{6n-6}\color{#C00}{(r+1)^2}\frac{r!}{6^r}\left[x^r\right]P_n(x)\tag7
$$
$$
\begin{array}{r|r|l}
n&\text{approx}&\text{variance of the number of rolls}\\\hline
1&0.0000&0\\
2&1.5264&\frac{160235}{104976}\\
3&4.4200&\frac{1385467181735}{313456656384}\\
4&8.1741&\frac{3970639068398634029855}{485758124386377007104}\\
5&12.5141&\frac{167282417942596577487510903436775}{13367494538843734067838845976576}\\
6&17.2823&\frac{299403979134389260700419343170913975}{17324272922341479351919144385642496}\\
7&22.3801&\frac{38453757121975432232112509661376820420488859015}{1718215241508606708609003009624888417152139264}\\
8&27.7411&\frac{76350278475830518207232272700236909606258581335}{2752248583871574368941325377477757056868941824}\\
9&33.3185&\frac{18816569501958632926522985216785742414806774312249329667113541895}{564748358308399579753663138099951559832606887511235138815000576}\\
10&39.0779&\frac{8077952785250811719054966016778836135365746066999551557114097296532094462513175}{206714095716819310132155904842979232279330627141833377324175114359098704920576}
\end{array}
$$